# Summing in a list in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble which has the date, day of the quarter, and a list of whether the days in quarter are sales days or not (1/0). I would like to sum the list of sales days (to get # of sales days left in the quarter) by summing from *day_num* to the end of *sales_day_list* So for the first day of Q2, 1993, I'd like to sum from 1:end of *sales_day_list* to get 64. On day 2, I'd like to sum from 2:end of *sales_day_list* etc.

Here is an example of my data (the output from dput)

> ```
> my_data= structure(list(DW_DATE_ID = structure(c(733622400, 733708800, 
> 733795200, 733881600, 733968000, 734054400), class = c("POSIXct", 
> "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), day_num = 1:6, sales_day_list = list(
>     c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
>     1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
>     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>     0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
>     1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), c(1, 0, 0, 
>     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>     0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
>     1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
>     1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
>     0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
>     1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
>     1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
>     0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>     1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
>     1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
>     0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>     1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
>     1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
>     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>     0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
>     1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
>     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>     0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
>     1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
>     1, 1, 0), c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>     0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
>     1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
>     1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
>     0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0))), row.names = c(NA, 
> -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
> ```

Comment: It might just be me, but I'm having trouble figuring out what you're trying to do. A short example of your expected output might help.

Answer (score 1):

Upon inspection, the `sales_day_list` is the same for each row, which makes sense since the sales days shouldn't change throughout the quarter.

To solve this problem, get the **day of the quarter** and the **sales days** as vectors, then write a function to apply the sum across the sales days vector, subsetting it by the day of the quarter.

```
x <- my_data$day_num # days as vector
y <- my_data$sales_day_list[[1]] # can be any one of them
sapply(x, function(x){sum(y[x:length(y)])}) # desired output
```

You can assign the output of the last line back into your data frame.

Answer (score 1):

First we can make a table of just the sales days, and count how many left in the qtr.

```
sales_days <- my_data[1,3] %>%   # Grab row 1, column 3
  tidyr::unnest() %>%
  rename(sales_day = sales_day_list) %>%
  mutate(day_num = row_number()) %>%
  arrange(-day_num) %>%
  mutate(remaining_sales = cumsum(sales_day)) %>%
  arrange(day_num)
```

Then we can attach this to `my_data`:

```
my_data2 <- my_data[,1:2] %>%
  left_join(sales_days)

head(my_data2)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  DW_DATE_ID          day_num sales_day remaining_sales
  <dttm>                <int>     <dbl>           <dbl>
1 1993-04-01 00:00:00       1         1              64
2 1993-04-02 00:00:00       2         0              63
3 1993-04-03 00:00:00       3         0              63
4 1993-04-04 00:00:00       4         1              63
5 1993-04-05 00:00:00       5         1              62
6 1993-04-06 00:00:00       6         1              61
```